# Send additional data payload to twilio client via android sdk

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am using twilio voice client for incoming calls using this code (https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android).
I am using my own server where this code is placed (https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-server-php) and I use placeCall.php for making calls to client.
My question is that, I want to send some additional data payload, for using it in my mobile app, which I am getting on onMessageReceived method of android application.
What should I do to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure this is completely possible yet, but it is something that is coming. I recommend getting in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) to enquire about the feature and see if they have any more information.

Comment: @philnash Thanks for the response. I already sent email to Twilio Support but no got no response until now.

Comment: @philnash Got response from Twilio and they say that it is not possible... :(

Comment: @philnash The only thing I am unable to do (which SDK does) is connect two parties within mobile app in incoming call. Please help me

Comment: I'm confused, sorry. What's the issue now. You can't send additional data over the Twilio client connection, but you could use some other channel for that. Are you able to connect calls using the Twilio Voice SDK?

Comment: @philnash Actually what I wanted to do is make a twilio client of my own. I am missing my calls, means I am not getting notifications for most of my incoming calls.Does it happen to you (not getting notifications for incoming calls)?

Comment: I am sorry, I really don't understand. Are you using Twilio Client to receive incoming calls? Are you saying that you aren't getting notifications for those calls? Or do you mean for regular phone calls? Perhaps you could start again and ask a new question?